# Libgdx MainMenu is not responding

Tags: java, libgdx

I defined a mainmenu class where I am Trying to show some images inside a table and make them respond for touches but when I define the call the class (just call it) inside the constructor of the main screen, the controls don't respond although I defined the mainmenu class in the same way of defining the controls class.
(notice when I use mainmenu object inside the main screen it renders the images and the controls but they don't respond for any click).
the main problem is happened when I call the mainmenu, the game is running but controls don't respond for touch. here is the code of the two classes:

```
public class Controller {
    public Viewport viewport;
    public Stage stage;
    public boolean upPressed;
    public boolean leftPressed;
    public boolean rightPressed;
    public boolean pausePressed;
    public static boolean visiblity;
    public Image buttonUp;
    public Image buttonDown;
    public Image buttonLeft;
    public Image buttonRight;
    public Image buttonpause;
    public OrthographicCamera camera;
    public Table table;
    public Table table1;
    public Table table2;

    //Constructor.
    public Controller(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(Fruits.V_WIDTH, Fruits.V_HIEGT, camera);
        stage = new Stage(viewport, spriteBatch);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        visiblity=false;
        //Buttons with images.
        buttonUp = new Image(new Texture("Pause.png"));
        buttonUp.setSize(30, 30);

        buttonUp.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                upPressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                upPressed = false;
            }
        });

        buttonLeft = new Image(new Texture("buttonleft.png"));
        buttonLeft.setSize(65, 65);
        buttonLeft.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                leftPressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                leftPressed = false;
            }
        });
        buttonRight = new Image(new Texture("buttonright.png"));
        buttonRight.setSize(65, 65);
        buttonRight.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                rightPressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                rightPressed = false;
            }
        });
        buttonpause = new Image(new Texture("pausing.png"));
        buttonpause.setSize(30, 30);

        buttonpause.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                pausePressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                pausePressed = false;
            }
        });

        //Table with buttons.

        table = new Table();
        table.left().bottom(); //Align to the left bottom.
        table.add(buttonLeft).size(buttonLeft.getWidth(), buttonLeft.getHeight()).spaceRight((viewport.getWorldWidth() / 10) * 6.5f);
       // table.add(buttonUp).size(buttonUp.getWidth(), buttonUp.getHeight()).spaceRight((viewport.getWorldWidth() / 10) * 6.5f);
        table.add(buttonRight).size(buttonRight.getWidth(), buttonRight.getHeight());

        stage.addActor(table);
        table1=new Table();
        table1.right().top();
        table1.setFillParent(true);
        //table1.add();
        table1.row().pad(25, 3, 0, 10);
        table1.add(buttonUp).size(buttonUp.getWidth(), buttonUp.getHeight()).spaceRight((viewport.getWorldWidth() / 10) * 6.5f);
        stage.addActor(table1);

        table2=new Table();
        table2.center();
        table2.setFillParent(true);
        //table1.add();
        table2.row().pad(25, 3, 0, 10);
        table2.add(buttonpause).size(buttonpause.getWidth(), buttonpause.getHeight()).spaceRight((viewport.getWorldWidth() / 10) * 6.5f);

        stage.addActor(table2);

    }
    public void draw() {
        stage.draw();
    }


    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }
    public boolean isUpPressed() {
        return upPressed;
    }

    public boolean isLeftPressed() {
        return leftPressed;
    }

    public boolean isRightPressed() {
        return rightPressed;
    }
    public boolean isPausePressed() {
        return pausePressed;
    }

}
```

code of mainmenu

```
public class MainMenu{
  /*  public Viewport viewport;
    public Stage stage;
    public boolean pausePressed;
    public boolean resumePressed;
    public boolean exitPressed;
    public Image buttonpause;
    public Image buttonDown;
    public Image buttonresume;
    public Image buttonexit;
    public OrthographicCamera camera;
    public Table table;
    public Table table2;

    //Constructor.
    public MainMenu(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(Fruits.V_WIDTH, Fruits.V_HIEGT, camera);
        stage = new Stage(viewport, spriteBatch);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        //Buttons with images.
        buttonpause = new Image(new Texture("pausing.png"));
        buttonpause.setSize(30, 30);

        buttonpause.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                pausePressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                pausePressed = false;
            }
        });

        buttonresume = new Image(new Texture("resume.png"));
        buttonresume.setSize(65, 65);
        buttonresume.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                resumePressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                resumePressed = false;
            }
        });
        buttonexit = new Image(new Texture("exit.png"));
        buttonexit.setSize(65, 65);
        buttonexit.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                exitPressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                exitPressed = false;
            }
        });

        //Table with buttons.
        table2=new Table();
        table2.center();
        table2.setFillParent(true);
        //table2.add();
        table2.row().pad(25, 3, 0, 10);
        table2.add(buttonpause).size(buttonpause.getWidth(), buttonpause.getHeight()).spaceRight((viewport.getWorldWidth() / 10) * 6.5f);
        table2.row().pad(25, 3, 0, 10);
        table2.add(buttonresume).size(buttonresume.getWidth(), buttonresume.getHeight());
        table2.row().pad(25, 3, 0, 10);
        table2.add(buttonexit).size(buttonexit.getWidth(), buttonexit.getHeight()).spaceRight((viewport.getWorldWidth() / 10) * 6.5f);
        stage.addActor(table2);

    }
    public void draw() {
        stage.draw();

    }

    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }
    public boolean isPausePressed() {
        return pausePressed;
    }

    public boolean isResumePressed() {
        return resumePressed;
    }

    public boolean isExitPressed() {
        return exitPressed;
    }
*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can only be one input processor set at a time, so only your most recent call to `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor` has any effect. So move that call to the `show()` method of your screens (if you're implementing Screen, otherwise do whatever the equivalent is in your structure).

You can also use an InputMultiplexer to combine multiple input processors into one if you want them to be able to work at the same time.

Comment: do I have to use InputMultiplexer If I want to handle the event of back button in android device.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can put `if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK))` in your render loop. Make sure you call `Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);` when starting up your game.

Comment: why is that Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);?

Comment: If you dont, the back button will perform it's default action of closing your game.